# PL/SQL - XML clob error

Tags: xml, oracle, plsql, clob, xmltype

I'm trying to test a PL/SQL procedure which takes an xml CLOB as a parameter

```
PROCEDURE example_proc(ex_xml CLOB) IS
BEGIN

/* Find the second < (skip over declaration) */
ln_position := instr(pc_shipment_xml, '<', 1, 2);
/* Find the space after the first tag */
ln_position := instr(pc_shipment_xml, ' ', ln_position, 1);
/* Set the first part of the XML clob */
lc_shipment_xml := substr(pc_shipment_xml, 1, ln_position - 1);
/* Skip the namespace */
ln_position     := instr(pc_shipment_xml, '>', ln_position, 1);
lc_shipment_xml := lc_shipment_xml || substr(pc_shipment_xml, ln_position);

/* Set the XML type */
lx_shipment_xml := xmltype(lc_shipment_xml); --RIGHT HERE IS WHERE IT ERRORS OUT
```

Here is the xml that I am passing in (as the ex_xml clob parameter):

```
    xml := 
'<Shipment>
  <OrderNumber>00000</OrderNumber>
   <ShipmentLines>
    <ShipmentLine>
      <OrderDetailId>000000</OrderDetailId>
      <LineNumber>0</LineNumber>
      <ItemId>00000</ItemId>
      <UnitId>0000000</UnitId>
      <BaseUom>X</BaseUom>
      <Quantity1>000</Quantity1>
    </ShipmentLine>
  </ShipmentLines>
</Shipment>';
```

and it errors out on that very last line with:

```
ORA-19202: Error occurred in XML processing
LPX-002255: end-element tag "ShipmentLines" does not match start-element tag "Shipment"
```

Please pardon my ignorance but this is my first time working with XML in PL/SQ, am I missing something with the formatting? As far as I can see I'm opening and closing my tags correctly. Any input at all is appreciated.

Comment: Do you really try to modify a XML document with `instr`, `substr` etc? Have a look at [XML Functions](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions002.htm#SQLRF51185)

Answer (score 0):

Running your code as

```
declare
  pc_shipment_xml CLOB := '<Shipment>
  <OrderNumber>00000</OrderNumber>
   <ShipmentLines>
    <ShipmentLine>
      <OrderDetailId>000000</OrderDetailId>
      <LineNumber>0</LineNumber>
      <ItemId>00000</ItemId>
      <UnitId>0000000</UnitId>
      <BaseUom>X</BaseUom>
      <Quantity1>000</Quantity1>
    </ShipmentLine>
  </ShipmentLines>
</Shipment>';
  lc_shipment_xml varchar2(2000);
  ln_position integer;
BEGIN
  /* Find the second < (skip over declaration) */
  ln_position := instr(pc_shipment_xml, '<', 1, 2);
  /* Find the space after the first tag */
  ln_position := instr(pc_shipment_xml, ' ', ln_position, 1);
  /* Set the first part of the XML clob */
  lc_shipment_xml := substr(pc_shipment_xml, 1, ln_position - 1);
  /* Skip the namespace */
  ln_position     := instr(pc_shipment_xml, '>', ln_position, 1) + 1;
  lc_shipment_xml := lc_shipment_xml || substr(pc_shipment_xml, ln_position);
  dbms_output.put_line(lc_shipment_xml);
end;
/
```

gives the following output:

```
<Shipment>
  <OrderNumber>00000</OrderNumber>

    <ShipmentLine>
      <OrderDetailId>000000</OrderDetailId>
      <LineNumber>0</LineNumber>
      <ItemId>00000</ItemId>
      <UnitId>0000000</UnitId>
      <BaseUom>X</BaseUom>
      <Quantity1>000</Quantity1>
    </ShipmentLine>
  </ShipmentLines>
</Shipment>
```

so it looks like you are stripping out the start ShipmentLines tag, but not the end tag

if you know the name of the tag to remove you could more simply remove both with

```
lc_shipment_xml := regexp_replace(pc_shipment_xml, '</?ShipmentLines>');
```

or getting the tag by position:

```
l_tag := regexp_substr(pc_shipment_xml, '<(\w+)>',1,3,'i',1);
lc_shipment_xml := regexp_replace(pc_shipment_xml, '</?' || l_tag || '>');
```

A better approach would be to use the xml funtions, something like this:

```
declare
  pc_shipment_xml CLOB := '<Shipment>
  <OrderNumber>00000</OrderNumber>
  <ShipmentLines>
    <ShipmentLine>
      <OrderDetailId>000000</OrderDetailId>
      <LineNumber>0</LineNumber>
      <ItemId>00000</ItemId>
      <UnitId>0000000</UnitId>
      <BaseUom>X</BaseUom>
      <Quantity1>000</Quantity1>
    </ShipmentLine>
  </ShipmentLines>
</Shipment>';
  lx_shipment_xml xmltype := xmltype(pc_shipment_xml);
  lx_shipline_xml xmltype := xmltype(pc_shipment_xml);
  lc_shipment_xml varchar2(2000);
BEGIN
  /* Set the XML type */
    select extract(lx_shipment_xml, '/Shipment/ShipmentLines/ShipmentLine') into lx_shipline_xml from dual;
    select deletexml(lx_shipment_xml, '/Shipment/ShipmentLines') into lx_shipment_xml from dual;
    select insertxmlafter(lx_shipment_xml, '/Shipment/OrderNumber', lx_shipline_xml) into lx_shipment_xml from dual;
    select xmlserialize(content lx_shipment_xml) into lc_shipment_xml from dual;
    dbms_output.put_line(lc_shipment_xml);
end;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

The way that I was parsing the xml required putting the `<?xml version="1.0"?>` at the beginning of the clob. The parsing methods are not my own code so changing the way I was doing that wasn't an option. Thanks